# Laravel - Using bundle to retrieve data from db

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-3, charisma

First of all, I'm new to Laravel and MVC environment. For this project, I'm using MySQL as database and Charisma as the bundle. I'm having difficulties when trying to retrieve data from db. I wonder if someone would guide me through all these problems.

1. If I'm using bundle, where do I put all the models, controllers and the routes? In `/application` folder, or in the bundle's folder itself?
2. When do I use `/application` folder, and when do I use Charisma folder? (obviously, I'm only using it for the front-end UI)
3. I have a record in my database table (named `user_links`) to test the data retrieval in Charisma View. How do I go about that?

I'm using this [CRUD Tutorial in Laravel](http://www.w3programmers.com/crud-with-pagination-in-laravel/) as a guide, but it's a little confusing when it comes to using bundle.

Ok, let me try do it my way. I'm going to do a Retrieval here. I hope someone can point out the mistake and guide me for a fix.:

**Table** name `user_links`:

```
id: int
user_id: varchar
link_title: text
link_url: text
```

**Model** `/application/models/user_links.php` (since Charisma doesn't have `/models` folder, I'm gonna use the default one):

```
class User_Link extends Eloquent{
}
```

**Controller** `bundles/charisma/controllers/user_link.php` (using Charisma controllers folder)

```
class Charisma_User_Link_Controller extends Base_Controller{

  public $restful = true;

  public function get_index(){
 $user_links =  User_Link(); 
return View::make('user_links.index')
->with('link_title', 'Link Title')
->with('link_url', 'URL');
  }
}
```

**View** `/bundles/charisma/views/pages/index.blade.php`:

```
<div >
@foreach($user_link->results as $user_links)
    {{ $user_links::link_title }}
    {{ $user_links::link_url }}
@endforeach
</div>
```

**Routes** `/bundles/charisma/routes.php`:

```
Route::controller('charisma::user_link');
```

That's all. Of course there will be some errors, but if you need something more please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should use application folder for your front end `UI` because [charisma](http://usman.it/themes/charisma/) is an [admin bundle](http://bundles.laravel.com/bundle/charisma) and it's been designed for applications, those have a back end support to setup and maintain various system configurations, like a custom `cms`.

In `Laravel-3` the `application` folder is the default place to keep your controllers, models and views in corresponding folders and also use the `application/routes.php` for routing your controllers.

But, if you want to use a different bundle as `charisma` then you should keep the bundle in the root of the bundle directory and add the bundle name to the array in `bundles.php` file. For example, I've used `charisma` as a bundle for my admin panel in one of my projects and the name of the folder was admin where I placed `charisma`'s files (I renamed charisma to admin)

```
return array(
    'admin' => array('handles' => 'hit_admin'), <-- added for admin bundle
    // more bundles..........
);
```

And my directory structure was `domain_root/bundles/admin` and admin was `charisma` (renamed) and also you have to use your bundles `routes.php` for controllers of that bundle. for example, in `domain_root/bundles/admin` I had a `routes.php` file and I've registered all routes for the admin bundle in that file and the admin bundle had it's own controllers, views, models and public folders. So, basically, I had to use those folders. All admin controllers were in `domain_root/bundles/admin/controllers` folder and same for the models and views too. Every bundle also has it's own public folder to keep it's own assets.

And in the `admin/routes.php` a route was something like this

```
Route::any('(:bundle)', array('as' => 'admin_home', 'uses' => 'admin::home@index'));
```

Also every controller in admin bundle can extend it's own base controller, for example, I used,

```
class Admin_Home_Controller extends Admin_Base_Controller {
    // ...
}
```

And there was a `base.php` file in `admin/controllers` folder which was the admin base controller and it was something like this

```
class Admin_Base_Controller extends Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        // Add assets for admin
        Asset::add('jQuery', 'js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js');
    }

    public function __call($method, $parameters)
    {
        return Response::error('404');
    }

}
```

For more information you can take a look at [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/build-your-first-admin-bundle-for-laravel/) and read the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs) too.